# Parsing list of dictionaries in Pandas column

Tags: json, python-3.x

I have a column in pandas dataframe which contains a list of dictionaries. I loaded the data from a csv file.

I referred similar posts in here and tried applying it.

But I am getting the error

"ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!"

I think I am missing something here. Could you please help?

```
df_new = pd.DataFrame({"ID":[1,2],"Items":[{'string': '[{"barcode":"50","quantity":5,"unitPrice":1.01,"discount":1.5,"productName":"Chamallows"},{"barcode":"51","quantity":2,"unitPrice":2.01,"discount":1.0,"productName":"Haribo"}]', 'provided': 'string'},{'string': '[{"barcode":"52","quantity":3,"unitPrice":1.01,"discount":1.5,"productName":"Beer"}]', 'provided': 'string'}]})
```

This is what I tried

```
df = (pd.DataFrame(df_new['Items'].to_dict())).T
[pd.DataFrame(x) for x in df['string']]
```

This is the expected output

```
ID  barcode discount    productName quantity    unitPrice
1   50  1.5         Chamallows     5             1.01
1   51  1           Haribo             2             2.01
2   52  1.5         Beer               3             1.01
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code, this will work for your case:

```
import ast
df_new = pd.DataFrame({"ID":[1,2],"Items":[{'string': '[{"barcode":"50","quantity":5,"unitPrice":1.01,"discount":1.5,"productName":"Chamallows"},{"barcode":"51","quantity":2,"unitPrice":2.01,"discount":1.0,"productName":"Haribo"}]', 'provided': 'string'},{'string': '[{"barcode":"52","quantity":3,"unitPrice":1.01,"discount":1.5,"productName":"Beer"}]', 'provided': 'string'}]})

df_ = pd.concat([df_new["ID"], ((pd.DataFrame(df_new['Items'].to_dict())).T).string.apply(ast.literal_eval)],axis=1).explode("string")
df_output = pd.concat([df_["ID"],pd.DataFrame(df_['string'].values.tolist(), index=df_.index)],axis=1)
```

Output:

```
ID  barcode quantity    unitPrice   discount    productName
0   1   50  5   1.01    1.5 Chamallows
0   1   51  2   2.01    1.0 Haribo
1   2   52  3   1.01    1.5 Beer
```

Comment: Thank you abheet. I am getting the error "AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'explode'"

Comment: Hi Joe, it's working fine for me. But I had updated the answer, please try now and let me know.

Comment: Thanks again. I am getting the same error. If I remove explode from the code then it's working but not getting the desired o/p. I am using python 3.7.3.

Comment: And pandas version are you using?? It works on pandas version >=0.25.0

Comment: Hi, I am using 0.24.2. I will update and let you know. Thanks a lot for supporting

Comment: It worked !  and I am getting the expected output. Thank you very much abheet. You’re the best. I wouldn’t have finished this on time without you. :)

Comment: Hey one more doubt. I am getting the issues "ValueError: malformed node or string: nan" when parsing the whole data frame. How to handle it ?

Comment: Need to check the data for that, can you provide me more info on that??

Comment: It was a file issue :) . Took a while to figure it out. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the list comprehension

```
[pd.DataFrame(x) for x in df['string']]
```

`x` is a string and not a iterable /list. So DataFrame constructor will fail to accept it.
One way is to load your string as json . But you need to verify whether it solves all your cases.

```
[pd.DataFrame(json.loads(x)) for x in df['string']]
```

Comment: Thanks Kris. I tried it and I am able to parse it now. But the column names are getting repeated. [  barcode  discount productName  quantity  unitPrice
 0      50       1.5  Chamallows         5       1.01
 1      51       1.0      Haribo         2       2.01,
   barcode  discount productName  quantity  unitPrice
 0      52       1.5        Beer         3       1.01]