# List Embedded in Column in Pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas

My data is structured as follows:

```
id                          text                                                created_at                  public_metrics
0   1372226235380666368     Senator Dianne Feinstein’s husband, Richard Bl...   2021-03-17T16:40:03.000Z    {'retweet_count': 13, 'reply_count': 11, 'like...               
1   1372224061225459713     Police said the suspect said he had a “sexual ...   2021-03-17T16:31:25.000Z    {'retweet_count': 20, 'reply_count': 20, 'like...               
2   1372223437381468166     Organizations that track hate groups and viole...   2021-03-17T16:28:56.000Z    {'retweet_count': 92, 'reply_count': 40, 'like...               
3   1372219606560075776     Breaking News: Biologists grew mice embryos ha...   2021-03-17T16:13:43.000Z    {'retweet_count': 74, 'reply_count': 49, 'like...               
4   1372217785082916873     RT @NickAtNews: Latest on Atlanta:\n• Gunman t...   2021-03-17T16:06:29.000Z    {'retweet_count': 14, 'reply_count': 0, 'like_...               
5   1372216261132845057     Today's Great Read:\n\nA grand estate in Engla...   2021-03-17T16:00:25.000Z    {'retweet_count': 12, 'reply_count': 10, 'like...
```

I need to break the public_metrics column into 4 separate columns by extracting the list.

I have looked at this: [Parsing list of dictionaries in Pandas column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58023047/parsing-list-of-dictionaries-in-pandas-column) but am unable to parse the code for this file setup.

Comment: I think you would attract more attempts at answers if you provided a copy-pasteable dataframe (or code that creates a small df).

Comment: ^^ also, I think what you are asking might be a duplicate if you can try `df.join(pd.DataFrame(df['public_metrics'].tolist(),index=df.index))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just loop through the keys of the dictionary in `public_metrics` and add columns to your dataframe, something like:

```
for k in ["retweet_count", "reply_count", ...]:
    df[k] = df["public_metrics"].apply(lambda d: d[k])
```

Then at the end, drop the original column:

```
del df["public_metrics"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Setup:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['id', 'text', 'public_metrics'], data=[[0, 'foo', {'retweet_count': 13, 'reply_count': 11}], [1, 'bar', {'retweet_count': 20, 'reply_count': 20}]])                                                     
>>> df                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
   id text                            public_metrics
0   0  foo  {'retweet_count': 13, 'reply_count': 11}
1   1  bar  {'retweet_count': 20, 'reply_count': 20}
```

Solution:

```
>>> pd.concat([df.drop('public_metrics', axis=1), pd.DataFrame(df['public_metrics'].tolist())], axis=1)                                                                                                                         
   id text  retweet_count  reply_count
0   0  foo             13           11
1   1  bar             20           20
```